# Flutter Websocket client ssl handshake failure

Tags: java, flutter, ssl, dart, ca

The server works correctly, tested with an echo client.

Altough when I run my app with:

```
 final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("wss://hostname:port");
    channel.sink.add('test');
    channel.stream.listen((message) {
      debugPrint(message);
      channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
```

The debug console exceptions with this recurring message:

```
E/flutter (19705): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (19705):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
```

I tried in many ways make my flutter app trust the Let`s Encrypt CA with no success.

Any response towards resolving my issue will be much appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that the site is improperly setup, i.e. either having a bad certificate or missing intermediate certificates. And the echo client might simply ignore such problems (browsers usually work around missing intermediate certificates, others don't). If you would provide the actual hostname and port and might be able to provide more details but you might also try to check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) - but be sure to use the same port as target.

Comment: According to SSLLabs: only my DNS CAA is incomplete, it also only uses TLS 1.2

Comment: DNS CAA and TLS 1.2 only do not matter regarding certificate validation.

Comment: Then idk what's wrong, its quite frustrating, I must have an encrypted communication. The weird thing is that sometimes the client is establishing an ssl handshake with the server, but most of the time, the exception is shown.

Comment: To cite myself: *"If you would provide the actual hostname and port and might be able to provide more details ..."*. Without these details it is impossible to say what's wrong. If it works sometimes but not always it would be interesting what the difference is in these scenarios. Different network?

Comment: Same network, same settings...

Answer (score 2):

```
    class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, i fixed it a week ago and forgot to post the answer.
It's more of a workaround but it's stable nevertheless...
I used an apache2 webserver that uses a reverse proxy to the websocket server.
Now the apache server has the certificate in place and I used s_client on openssl to check whether the browser/client accepts the certificate, it did after I used apache2 as a reverse proxy.